# French's 'ne explétif' in English?

Tags: french

●[Source:](https://books.google.com/books?id=sHU_cu9jhLwC&pg=PA249&lpg=PA249&dq=ne+expletif+in+english&source=bl&ots=ohauvYZxuQ&sig=vZD73K8d4Yi79u65SA202lnvFWU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9J3eVNXzEIyfgwT_1ICQCA&ved=0CBwQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=ne%20expletif%20in%20english&f=false) p 249, *Zizek's Ontology ...*, by Adrian Johnston

●●[Source:](https://books.google.com/books?id=JPYNAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA65&dq=%22je+redoute+que%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qAXhVPfUN4zasATGq4GACg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22je%20redoute%20que%22&f=false) p 65, *L'Odyssé d'Homère: tr. en français, Volume 2*, translated by Dugas Montbel

> ● Bruce Fink helpfully compares the French *ne explétif* [hereafter abbreviated as NE] to certain employments of the English 
>   word **but**
>   (as in, for example, "I can 't help **but** think that... " or "I cannot deny **but** that . .. ")
>    Fink contends that the French **ne** and the English **but** are each means of expressing an attitude of ambivalence toward the meaningful content of the sentence uttered (an attitude coloring the 
>   position of the subject of enunciation) without, for all that, disrupting or repudiating ♦  the literal meaning of the sentence per se  as the sense established in the form of an utterance.<sup>29</sup> Philippe Van Haute claims that the occurrence of the NE makes for the difference between, in its absence, the "impersonal" phenomenon of a simple assertive sentence in 
>   which the subject of enunciation 's intention-to-signify coincides with (or 
>   collapses/fades into) the thus-established position of the subject of the 
>   utterance, and, in its presence, the "personal" phenomenon of indicating, through the **ne**, an affectively inflected distance between the speaker 
>   (i.e., enunciation) and the significance of what the speaker spoke (i.e., 
>   utterance).<sup>30</sup> ♦  The signifier **ne** or **but** marks, within the uttered sentence, 
>   the enunciator's unease with what he or she uttered.

Although [I didn't understand the long sentences](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/42834/8712) surrounded by ♦ , I include the above should it help anyone. [Negatives still trouble me](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/32843/8712), but I cancel the double negatives in Fink's comparisons:

> 1. I can<s>[not]</s> help **<s>but</s>** think that... "   = 1.1. I think that
>   2. I cannot deny **<s>but</s>** that  = 2.1. I deny that

Q1. In 1.1 and 2.1, there's nothing negative. So  where can the French adverb « **ne** » possibly lie?

I exemplify a verb requiring the NE with *[redouter](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/negation_form_2.htm)* (which I arbitrarily chose):

> ●●Si vous tardez en vous armant contre ce 
>   rocher, je redoute que, s'élancant de nouveau, 
>   Scylla
>   **n'** engloutisse autant de vos compagnons qu'elle a de 
>   têtes.
>
> My translation: 3. ...I dread that, soaring up again, Scylla swallows as many of your companions as she has heads.

Q2. In 3, I never used Fink's double negation? So what does he mean?

Comment: *"I cannot help but think"* means *"I think that"*; however *"I cannot deny but that"* means *"I don't deny that"*. In both cases, the *"but"* does not change the meaning. (I think the idea is that the *ne* does not change the meaning in your sentence 3, although I'm not sure the parallel is accurate.)

Comment: And to reassure you on your English comprehension I don't understand the last sentences between the ♦'s, either.

Comment: Checking [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cannot+but+wonder%2Ccannot+help+but+wonder%2Ccannot+help+wondering+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20but%20wonder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20help%20but%20wonder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20help%20wondering%3B%2Cc0), I am absolutely amazed to find that the *"cannot help but ..."* construction is relatively new to English grammar (20th century).

Comment: *I cannot help but think* has the same technical meaning as *I think*, but as Bruce Fink contends, *cannot help but* establishes a unique ***emotional posture*** toward the conclusion. *I think* as opposed to *I am compelled to think (against my emotional inclination)*. https://books.google.com/books?id=LCxKAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA31&dq=%22can+but%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MCThVJumMvSMsQS3woCICQ&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22can%20but%22&f=false

Comment: The French examples in [the page you link to](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/negation_form_2.htm) sound a bit artificial (as expected in such a document). There, using "*ne*" doesn't change the meaning, or add or remove any emphasis IMO. In fact, most people would say "Il est parti avant qu'on ait décidé" instead of "*Il est parti avant que nous n'ayons décidé.*", which sounds exactly like "[...] qu'on n'ait décidé" anyway. Where *ne* is particularly useful in French is to let you distinguish between "Je ne peux pas dormir." and "Je peux ne pas dormir.", but that's a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

*[Cannot but](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cannot+but)* behaves as a set phrase in English:

> Idioms
>
> 2. *cannot but*, have no alternative but to:

The double negative with ***but*** is used to convey an ambivalence toward the inescapable outcome, and adding the word ***help*** to form *cannot help but*, seems to multiply the emotional intensity of that ambiguity. In 1892, *[The Foundations of Rhetoric](https://books.google.com/books?id=nXURAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA162&dq=%22i%20cannot%20help%20but%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HXnhVOP5CumCsQS4gILABg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22i%20cannot%20help%20but%22&f=false)* pp. 161-162 compared the expressions "Can But" and "*Cannot But*"

> "Can but" brings before the mind only one possibility; "cannot but"
>   suggests two opposite courses, but affirms that in the case in hand
>   only one of these is possible...
>
> "You *cannot but* realize that you are" means you cannot help
>   **realizing that you are, you cannot believe that you are not.**
>
> "You can but realize that you are", means you can only realize, you cannot do more than realize, that you are...
>
> "He *could not but* speak" is equivalent to "He *could not help but* speak,"
>   *Help*...is tautological.

In 1846, the *[Horatii Tragedy](https://books.google.com/books?id=XioEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA38&dq=%22i%20cannot%20help%20but%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HXnhVOP5CumCsQS4gILABg&ved=0CFAQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22i%20cannot%20help%20but%22&f=false)* uses the phrase *cannot help but*, in a dialogue to evoke the emotional compulsion of fear:

> *Horatia*: What, art thou weeping?
>
> *Mysis*: Yes, my lady.
>
> *Horatia*: What ails the? What's amiss?
>
> *Mysis*: Nay, ***I cannot help but*** weep, my lady.
>
> *Horatia*: But tell me thy sorrow, good wench ; peradventure I may
>   comfort thee.
>
> *Mysis*: Why, to be plain with thee, sweet mistress ; I am weeping about
>   Bubo...I have bethought me of so many risks, and perils, and dangers,
>   and mischiefs, the which poor Bubo may run against, ***I cannot help*** but weep.

Again in 1846, *[The Christian](https://books.google.com/books?id=fYAXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA267&dq=%22i%20cannot%20help%20but%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6HjhVKPsGYe1sASUq4KwCg&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22i%20cannot%20help%20but%22&f=false)* expresses emotional ambivalence in a religious conflict:

> I cannot think, or feel, or talk, or act on **this** principle at all.
>   My thoughts, my feeling, my talk, my actions, go all on the
>   **opposite** principle of liberty. I ***cannot help but*** feel that there are some things which deserve blame, and others which deserve praise.
>   I *cannot* *help* blaming myself, if I do wrong, and I *cannot* *help*
>   praising or approving myself, if I do right. And I *cannot* *help* feeling
>   that there is a difference between right and wrong.

[*Beuachampe*](https://books.google.com/books?id=_98-AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA143&dq=%22i%20can%20not%20help%20but%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-HfhVO-yA9O0sATdj4LAAQ&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBTgK#v=onepage&q=%22i%20can%20not%20help%20but%22&f=false) in 1856, uses the expression to capture an internal conflict with fate:

> ***I can not help but*** tell it. An instinct, which I dare not disobey,
>   commands me; and truly, when I think of the instinct which told me
>   that you would come--made you known to me as the avenger from the
>   first moment when I saw you--and has thus forced you, as it were, in my
>   own despite, upon my fearful secret--I almost feel as if there is a
>   divine, **at least a fated compulsion**...

Almost every [use in written English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20cannot%20help%20but&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20can%20not%20help%20but%3B%2Cc0) was in the context of emotional ambivalence, conflict or compulsion:

In 1892, A Doctor of the [*Indiana State Medical Association*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0OVXAAAAMAAJ&q=%22i%20can%20not%20help%20but%22&dq=%22i%20can%20not%20help%20but%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-HfhVO-yA9O0sATdj4LAAQ&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAjgK) expressed his ambivalence while confronting a prevailing medical opinion on the treatment of pelvic peritonitis:

> I have seen so many of these cases operated upon, so many that had
>   previously been tested with electricity and not made better, but made
>   worse, that ***I can not help but*** believe that it is good doctrine,
>   when you have a case of recurring attacks of pelvic peritonitis,
>   "hands off" with your electric machine.

In 1987 hearings on the [*Alaska Arctic National Wildlife Refuge*](https://books.google.com/books?id=HesFAAAAIAAJ&q=%22i%20can%20not%20help%20but%22&dq=%22i%20can%20not%20help%20but%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zHLhVNjND4uZNsqJg6gK&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAw), a representative expresses emotional ambiguity toward the evidence presented by a witness:

> I ***can not help but*** note that when you look at the rewards that might
>   come from development on the North Slope in terms of total gas and oil
>   that might be discovered on the North Slope or in ANWR, you use the
>   lowest possible prediction. And when you talk about potential damage, you use the highest possible prediction.

**Interpretation**: *I must note, but I can't believe I have to note, such an obvious bias.* The same interpretive formula is applied to *I cannot help but **think***:

> *I am compelled to think, but I cannot believe (or like that) I must think.*

---

The expression *I cannot **deny** but that*, generates the same sense of emotional ambivalence toward the *denial*:

> *I cannot deny, but I cannot believe (or like that) I  cannot deny.*

---

### Conclusion:

Fink's thesis is that this use of *but* (and especially *help but*) behaves like *ne explétif*, implying a subtle emotional distance from an inescapable conclusion. When the OP eliminates both negatives of the double negative, that emotional ambivalence is incorrectly removed.

*I cannot help but think*, is similar to *I think* in meaning, but they are definitely **not identical** expressions.

*I cannot deny but that* is similar to *I cannot deny* in meaning, but they are definitely not identical expressions.

---

dictionary.reference.com

books.google.com/ngrams/graph